# scale incoming metric data for representation in cubism

Tags: d3.js, scale, remap, cubism.js

i have a data set being returned as a `cubism`'s `metric` such that it has values

```
0 = very bad
1 = okay
2 = bad
```

i can write a `d3.scale` such that

```
var ord = d3.scale.ordinal( [ 0, 1, 2, null ] ).range( [ -2, 2, -1, null ] );
for( var i=0; i<=2; i++ ) {
  console.log( i + ': ' + ord(i) );
}
console.log(  'null: ' + ord(null) );
```

and the terminal returns

```
0: -2
1: 2
2: -1
null: null
```

looks good... however, when i try applying this scale to the cubism horizon chart, the chart renders fine, except the data represented doesn't show bad values as negative and good as positive:

```
  d3.select("body").selectAll(".horizon")
    .data( metrics )
  .enter().insert("div", ".bottom")
    .attr("class", "horizon")
  .call(
    context.horizon()
      .scale( d3.scale.ordinal([ 0, 1, 2, null ]).range([ -2, 2, -1, null ]) )
  );
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't seem to work? Does the graph render incorrectly or not at all? Or is something else the issue?

Comment: the graph renders fine, but the scaling function doesn't appear to be applied (ie 'bad' data isn't negative).

Answer (score 0):

check horizon.extent([extent])

https://github.com/square/cubism/wiki/Horizon